# How to save string (username password) in encrypted form in database, and decrypt when, login by user

Tags: c++, authentication

Good morning all,
I am using c++ and also using wxWidget, In backend i m using MySql, i want to save user name and password in encrypted form inside the database,
when user will try to login,I will decrypt the data for authentication,
Is there any headerfiles in c++ who can handle encryption or decryption?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't encrypt the password, you don't want people's passwords to be recoverable. If they forget them then reset the password to something else. Don't ever store passwords or encrypted passwords which can be used to get the original password.

What you should do is:

- Generate random [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).
- Append or prepend the salt value to the user's password.
- [Hash](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function&ei=--yKTY23BYi4vgOFnNzQDg&usg=AFQjCNGfdPt0KBqdfxD5apPU4c1nv41Q9Q) the combination of password and salt (using something strong, like SHA256).
- Store the user name, the hashed value and the salt in the database.

When the user attempts to sign in:

- Load the salt value associated with the username.
- Append or prepend (ie. do the same as when they registered) the salt to the supplied password.
- Hash the combination, compare that to the stored hash. If they're different, sign-in fails.

Comment: thank you sir,How to implement random salt and hash in my c++ program, I did not implement it before, i only read out this.. any hint which will helpful to implement it in c++.

Comment: @rohitamitpathak The hash, I gave details about below. The random salt, you just generate a random string (use [rand](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand) to fill up a string of some length) and prepend it to the password before hashing. You need a different salt for each user (generate it at the same time that you create the user account), and you need to make sure you use the *same* salt every time you hash the user's password. So store the salt in the user's account in the database.

Comment: @oj-how to use salt and hash in c++? i got the logic but its look hard to implement, which header files and function i should use for salt and hash?

Comment: @rohitamitpathak I told you the details in a comment to my answer how to hash. See the [sha manpage](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/sha.html) but replace SHA1 with SHA256. The header is `#include <openssl/sha.h>` and the function is `SHA256`. To generate the salt, use [any random number generator](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand) in a loop to fill a string with random bytes.

Comment: your reply sir, is very appreciable and crystal clear.
Thank you very much for : 
1 - giving the good pratice.
2 - clearly describing how to implement it.
I must admit i would have SHA256 the password and store it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, on the crypto side, you won't want to encrypt *usernames* or you'll have no way to look them up. Passwords, though, you are right, should be stored encrypted, because if your database is compromised, you don't want people having access to everybody's passwords.

Usually, though, you don't *encrypt* passwords and decrypt them for authentication. You *hash* them. You get a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) (such as [SHA-256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2)) and run the password through that function. For example, if my password was "binoculars", I run it through SHA-256 and get:

```
a0e23a0813c2b152222f28830be966f4eb0fd8ccbb4b487b7688c2749e754a72
```

(that's a binary string, expressed in hexadecimal) so you store the above string in the database. Note that if someone got their hands on that string, there is absolutely no way to figure out that my original password was "binoculars".

Now when I come to authenticate, I supply the password "binoculars" and you run it through the hash algorithm and get the exact same string as above -- so it is the correct password. If I gave any other password, it would hash to a different string, and I can't log in.

Now on to libraries. There are lots of different libraries which will give you hash functions such as SHA-256. One you may try is [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/). I do recommend SHA-256. MD5 and SHA-1 are older hash functions that may have cryptographic weaknesses; SHA-256 has no known cryptographic weaknesses.

Comment: This is a good answer, the only thing you're missing is `salt`.

Comment: @OJ I didn't want to go into too much detail but absolutely right ... OJ's answer goes into salting which is something you should do. The reason for it is that if *two* people use "binoculars", you will see that they both have the same hash and guess that it will be a common word. In fact, an attacker might already know that the hash for "binoculars" is `a0e23a...`. With the salt, everybody's hash is different even if they use the same password.

Comment: thank you sir,i got the concept but how i can implement in c++, i did not use hash function before, can u give me guideline regarding implement it.

Comment: You know what, forget Crypto++. I can't understand it. Instead, look at [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org), a C library. It has a SHA256 function -- it seems to be undocumented but it is the same as the [SHA1 function](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/sha.html). Just allocate `SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH` bytes of memory for `digest`, and call `SHA256(password, strlen(password), digest)`. This will write the hash of the password into `digest`, which you can then store in the database. `SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH` is the length of the hash output.

Comment: But as OJ said, don't call it *directly* on the password, first salt the password.

Answer (score 1):

You don't decrypt the data from MySQL but encrypt the data that was supplied to the user. Then you compare it to the one  in MySQL.

Hashing algorithms are not meant to be decryptable.

EDIT: focusing my comment on hashing.

Comment: Encryption _is_ supposed to be decrypted. If you want something to be encoded without the original data being recoverable you should use a hash. Hashes are (or at least should be ;)) one-way.

Comment: You are right on that, I should be talking only about hashes.

Comment: I fixed my answer to reflect what OJ said.

Answer (score 0):

A little beside the point, but saving encrypted passwords is not the best option out there, as it means you can still calculate the original password from the information stored in the database. The common practice is to save a salted hash of the password, and when users log in, compare the stored salted hash to the one calculated from the password they were trying to login with.

Answer (score 0):

What is the need of decrypting?

Encrypt the username and password store it in table

Then encrypt the inputted username and password compare both

Comment: No, _do not_ encrypt anything. Leave the username as is, and hash the password + salt.

Comment: @OJ Or encrypt it with a public key (per user) that you have lost the private key for -- that's equivalent to hashing with a salt :) (Note, this is a joke post... there is no benefit to doing it this way.)

Comment: @OJ sorry i used the term encrypt actually i mean using a hash value , but adding salt to to password it's a bit complex na? sha256 and sha 512 are seldom more powerful encoding so why theextra measures

Comment: @mgiuca True, but you're doing the equivalent of a hash :) (joke noted ;))

Comment: No apology needed mate. Salt is required because you want to make sure that when users have the same password that the hash that is created is different. If you hash "foo", you'll get a value. You'll get that value EVERY time. So if two users have the same password, you'll get the same hash. This helps potential attackers. So the best thing to do is add something random (ie `salt`) to each password and hash the combination hence resulting in a different stored hash value. It's not that complex to implement, and is a security improvement.